# Two threads entering synchronized methods of runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

Here is a code i am having problem with --

```
public class WaitTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner rr = new Runner();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(rr,"T1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(rr,"T2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class Runner implements Runnable{
    int i=0;
    public void run(){
        try{
            if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T1")){
                bMethod();
                aMethod();
            }
            else{
                aMethod();
                bMethod();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    public synchronized void aMethod() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("i="+i+",Now going to Wait in aMethod "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.currentThread().wait();
        System.out.println("Exiting aMethod "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public synchronized void bMethod() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("i="+i+",Now going to Wait bMethod "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        i=5;
        notifyAll();
        System.out.println("Exiting bMethod "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
i=0,Now going to Wait bMethod T1
Exiting bMethod T1
i=5,Now going to Wait in aMethod T1
i=5,Now going to Wait in aMethod T2
```

My question is :

> Why T2 enters in `aMethod` while `T1` is waiting inside? and Why `T2` prints
>   `i=5` in `aMethod.`

Comment: I am surprised that `Thread.currentThread().wait()` did not throw `IllegalMonitorStateException`. `wait` should be called on `anObject` only when the current thread is in a `synchronized (anObject) { .. }` block.

Comment: Good catch, @BinilThomas. Now I wonder the same. It would work if this was using the "extend `Thread`" approach since in that case `aMethod` would see that `Thread` as `this`. Notice also that, taking into account your finding, `notifyAll` notifies a completely unrelated monitor.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ah! I ran the code on my machine and it is deceptive :). An `IllegalMonitorStateException` **is** thrown, but that is caught and ignored by the `run` method. That is why both threads die abruptly, without printing the `Exiting aMethod` message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute `wait`, your thread releases the lock and enters the wait state. At this time the other thread is allowed to enter the method. You are using a single instance of `Runnable` so when one thread sets it to 5, that's what the other thread reads.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** `wait` will **immediately release the lock**, and handover the lock to the other thread.

**2.** `notify` will release the lock **only when the closing parenthesis** of the synchronized block
   is reached.

**3.** As there is **only one instance of Runnable here**, its after the i = 5, and when the synchronized block ends..then the lock is released.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not doing the `wait-notify` pattern. The `Thread.currentThread().wait()` call throws an `IllegalMonitorStateException`, which is caught and ignored by the `run` method. Both `T1` and `T2` throws this exception, and hence you do not see the line `Exiting aMethod` printed.

The `notify` call in `bMethod` is wasted, because no thread ever `wait`s on the intrinsic lock of the `rr Runnable`.